# Bluetooth LE Enumeration with DevicePicker issue

Tags: c#, bluetooth, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing an application to enumerate Bluetooth LE devices, showing them in standard `DevicePicker` and connect to specific device.

Connecting works fine in my code, but I have a problem with enumeration. To display devices, I have to enumerate them with other app, like Bluetooth LE Explorer from Microsoft. Otherwise `DevicePicker` is empty. And after that, when list of devices is showing them, if I turn off BLE peripheral it is still on the list.

I have read about `DeviceWatcher`, but I found only examples about making custom UI using that watcher, but it is important to me to use `DevicePicker`. I couldn't make it work with my `DevicePicker`.

Here is a code of my picker:

```
picker = new DevicePicker();
picker.DeviceSelected += ConnectToDevice;
picker.Filter.SupportedDeviceSelectors.Add(
BluetoothLEDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(false));
picker.Filter.SupportedDeviceSelectors.Add(
BluetoothLEDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(true));
picker.Show(new Rect(0, 0, 200, 500), Windows.UI.Popups.Placement.Below);
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: I have tested your code on my PC and it enumerates fine. Could you try uninstalling the app and rebuilding it? Also - please try `PickSingleDeviceAsync` method instead of `Show`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried what you said, but it still the same. I modified my code, added normal Bluetooth devices to enumerate and it is discovering my standard Bluetooth devices normally. And thanks for PickSingleDeviceAsync, works good!