# C# - Bluetooth LE DevicePicker with Custom Filter

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth-lowenergy, filtering

I'm trying to add a custom filter to my DevicePicker using System.ItemNameDisplay

I've been searching the internet, finding examples, and testing different implementations but nothing has worked

I can use any of the built in DeviceSelectors from the BluetoothLEDevice class and they work fine but for my specific application I need the DevicePicker to only show devices whose name starts with a certain string [ProductNameStart] where [ProductNameStart] is a hard-coded string representing the starting characters of the devices I want to include on the DevicePicker

I've looked through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/deviceenumerationandpairing/) example (specifically Scenario 6) and it claims that the AQS can be used in the DevicePicker but doesn't show how.

I also created another project using DeviceWatcher and that works exactly like I intended using this constructor

```
string deviceFilter = "System.ItemNameDisplay:~<\"[ProductNameStart]\"";
string[] rp = { };DeviceWatcher deviceWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(deviceFilter,rp,DeviceInformationKind.AssociationEndpoint);
```

I've tried the following implementations for DevicePicker with no luck

```
DevicePicker devicePicker = new DevicePicker();

//devicePicker.RequestedProperties.Add("System.ItemNameDisplay"); // Doesn't help anything
//devicePicker.Filter.SupportedDeviceSelectors.Add("System.ItemNameDisplay:~<\"[ProductNameStart]\"");  // Doesn't Work
//devicePicker.Filter.SupportedDeviceSelectors.Add(BluetoothLEDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromDeviceName("System.ItemNameDisplay:~<\"[ProductNameStart]\"")); // Doesn't Work
//devicePicker.Filter.SupportedDeviceSelectors.Add(BluetoothLEDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromDeviceName("[ProductNameStart]")); // Doesn't Work
//devicePicker.Filter.SupportedDeviceSelectors.Add(BluetoothLEDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromDeviceName(":~<\"[ProductNameStart]\"")); // Doesn't Work
//devicePicker.Filter.SupportedDeviceSelectors.Add(BluetoothLEDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromDeviceName("~<\"[ProductNameStart]\"")); // Doesn't Work
//devicePicker.Filter.SupportedDeviceSelectors.Add(BluetoothLEDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromDeviceName("\"[ProductNameStart]\"")); // Doesn't Work
```

### Resources:

SO Posts:
[Bluetooth LE Enumeration with DevicePicker issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48379297/bluetooth-le-enumeration-with-devicepicker-issue)
[AQS syntax when providing a filter for BLE scanning in UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48909496/aqs-syntax-when-providing-a-filter-for-ble-scanning-in-uwp)

Other Posts:
[Displaying the device picker in a UWP application](https://putridparrot.com/blog/displaying-the-device-picker-in-a-uwp-application/)
[Build a device selector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/build-a-device-selector?source=recommendations)
[Using Advanced Query Syntax Programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-advancedquerysyntax?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
[UWP: Working with Bluetooth devices (part 1)](https://baydachnyy.com/2017/04/28/uwp-working-with-bluetooth-devices-part-1/)

Comment: Instead of device picker create custom device selection dialog and use BluetoothLeAdvertisementWatcher to find and filter required devices.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Thanks for commenting but I would much prefer to use a DevicePicker. The DeviceWatcher I created works fine but I can't get the filter to work when creating a DevicePicker which is what I'd like to solve